# Load simple XML from string

Tags: php, simplexml

My problem: my received string size is ca. 4 MB

and this string doesn't not load in `simplexml_load_string (return bool(false))`.

The data is received with `SoapClient`.

How can I load this string in xml?

Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('mydomain.com',array("trace"=> 1,"exceptions" => 0,'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
$result=$client->GetArlistaAuth(array('pid'=>$pid,'partnerkod'=>$partnerkod, 'authcode'=>$authcode));
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```

Comment: I guess a part fall off your question, what is the content of the data you received (`$result`)?

Comment: print your ($result) first

Comment: echo $result is noting, but var_dump($result) is: [code]<valasz xmlns="" verzio="1.0"><arak><ar><cikkid>902</cikkid><cikkszam>GD45015</cikkszam><listaar>3700,0000000</listaar><ar>3700,0000000</ar>[/code] and this more....

Comment: try DOMDocument maybe (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php)

Comment: my new code is:

$reader = new XMLReader();

$reader->xml($f);

$i = 0;

foreach($reader->read() as $item){
$i++;
echo($reader->readString()."<br>");
}
 echo $i." rows";

this code not really working, because rows is:


only third rows is good.
and end of loop not write $i
why?